# How to take different types of elements from Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Here I got two hash sets:

```
var vertexes = new HashSet[String]()
var edges = new HashSet[RDFTriple]() //RDFTriple is a class
```

I want to put them into a map like this:

```
var graph = Map[String, HashSet[_]]()
graph.put("e", edges)
graph.put("v", vertexes)
```

But now I want to take vertexes and edges respectively but failed. I have tried something like the following:

```
val a = graph.get("v")
a match {    
  case _ => val v = a 
}
val b = graph.get("e")
b match {
  case _ => val e = b
}
```

But `v` and `e` are recognized as `Option[HashSet[_]]` while I want are `HashSet[String]` and `HashSet[RDFTriple]`.

How can I do this?

I will apprecicate it so much cuz it bothers me too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use different types in the same `Map`, however you could some the problem by using `Some` and `asInstanceOf` like this:

```
val v = a match {    
  case Some(a) => a.asInstanceOf[HashSet[String]]
  case None    => // do something
}
```

Note that the assignment `val v = ...` is done outside the `match` to allow usage of the variable afterwards. The `match` for the edges is similar.

---

However, **a better solution** would be to use a case class for the graph. Then you would avoid a lot of hassle.

```
case class Graph(vertexes: HashSet[String], edges: HashSet[RDFTriple])

val graph = Graph(vertexes, edges)
val v = graph.vertexes // HashSet[String]
val e = graph.edges    // HashSet[RDFTriple]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That is what I want